# skybox boxgeometry does not show up. There is only a black screen shown

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to write a code for three.js that uses skybox which is a cube and each side has a picture, but the cube does not show up and there is only black screen being show when i run the file.

I think the problem is from the dev or three.min.js script. however I used the dev script for my previous work which works, but it does not for this particular file for some reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bad.css" />
        <title>My first three.js app</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src = "OrbitControls.js"></script>

        <script>
            // Our Javascript will go here.
            let scene, camera, renderer;
      function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,45,30000);
        camera.position.set(-900,-200,-900);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
        controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);
        controls.minDistance = 500;
        controls.maxDistance = 1500;

        let materialArray = [];
        let texture_ft = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'arid2_ft.jpg');
        let texture_bk = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'arid2_bk.jpg');
        let texture_up = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'arid2_up.jpg');
        let texture_dn = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'arid2_dn.jpg');
        let texture_rt = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'arid2_rt.jpg');
        let texture_lf = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'arid2_lf.jpg');

        materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_ft }));
        materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_bk }));
        materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_up }));
        materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_dn }));
        materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_rt }));
        materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_lf }));

        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++)
           materialArray[i].side = THREE.BackSide;
        let skyboxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000);
        let skybox = new THREE.Mesh( skyboxGeo, materialArray );
        scene.add( skybox );
        animate();
      }
      function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
      init();


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the result I get is just a black screen but its supposed to be a skybox which is a cube with pictures on each side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I notice is that you're importing Three.js twice:

- "three.min.js"
- "https://raw.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.js"

I believe that might be breaking your build. Are you getting any errors in the console? It could also be that "OrbitControls.js" is not available in that location.

Finally, as a suggestion, you don't need all that code to make a skybox. You can simply use a `CubeTextureLoader` to get it up and running in about 7 lines of code, as demonstrated in [its documentation page](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/CubeTextureLoader)